# How do you write a class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to define a class in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/whats-the-best-way-to-define-a-class-in-javascript)

How do you write a class in Javascript?  Is it even possible?

Comment: Ack. "javascript" got edited to "Javascript" rather than "JavaScript."

Comment: I prefer jAvAsCrIpt. It is the correct way.

Answer (score 7):

Well, JavaScript is a Prototype-Based language, it does not have classes, but you can have classical inheritance, and other behavior reuse patterns through object cloning and prototyping.

Recommended articles:

- [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
- [JavaScript Classical Inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html)
- [JavaScript Private Members](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)
- [Class-Based vs. Prototype-Based Languages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Class-Based_vs._Prototype-Based_Languages)

Answer (score 3):

```
function Foo() {
   // constructor
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    // bar function within foo
}
```

Comment: I think you have an extra "function" at the beginning of `bar`. :-)

Comment: Yeah.
Also, don't forget to mention that you have to use new Foo().

Comment: whoops fixed, im so not used to writing javascript oo.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript uses prototype-based OO by default.

However, if you're using prototype library, for example, you can use Class.create().

http://prototypejs.org/api/class/create

It would let you to create (or inherit) a class, after that you would instantiate its instances with new.

Other libraries probably have similar facilities.

Comment: Some do. jQuery doesn't, as it expects that you'll be more likely to deal with jQuery collections than with classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a library like prototype or jQuery its a lot easier but the legacy way is to do this.

```
function MyClass(){
}
MyClass.prototype.aFunction(){ 
}

var instance = new MyClass();
instance.aFunction();
```

You can read more on it here http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2008/09/javascript-classes-for-n00bs/

Answer (score 0):

It's "sort of" possible.  [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) has some built-in help with writing classes in JS.  Take a look at [this thorough description](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html) of how you can do it.

```
var namedClass = Class.create({
    initialize: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
});
var instance = new namedClass('Foobar');
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is based on objects, not classes. It uses prototypal inheritance, not classical inheritance.

JavaScript is malleable and easily extensible. As a result, there are many libraries that add classical inhertance to JavaScript. However, by using them you risk writing code that's difficult for most JavaScript programmers to follow.