# Is there any reason to use Object.create() or new in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, object-create

I've been using the `new` keyword in JavaScript so far. I have been reading about `Object.create` and I wonder if I should use it instead. What I don't quite get is that I often need to run construction code, so I don't see how `Object.create` is going to work at all since it does not trigger any functions to run.

Could anyone tell me, In which case should I use `Object.create` instead of `new`?

Comment: See answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-ja

Comment: See this as well with all new answers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/whats-the-best-way-to-define-a-class-in-javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So far, if you want to create an object, you can only use literals:

```
var obj = {};
```

or the `Object` constructor.

```
var obj = Object();
```

But none of these methods let you specify the *prototype* of the created object.

This is what you can do with `Object.create` now. It lets you create a new object and sets the first argument as prototype of the new object. In addition, it allows you to set properties of the new object provided as second argument.

It is similar to doing something like this (without the second argument):

```
function create(proto) {
    var Constr = function(){};
    Constr.prototype = proto;
    return new Constr();
}
```

So if you are using a construct similar to this, this when you wanted to use `Object.create`.

It is not a replacement for `new`. It is more an addition to make creating single objects which should inherit from another object simpler.

Example:

I have an object `a`:

```
var a = {
   someFunction: function() {}
};
```

and I want `b` to extend this object. Then you can use `Object.create`:

```
b = Object.create(a);
b.someOtherFunction = function(){};
```

Whenever you have a constructor function, but you only instantiate **one** object from it, you might be able to replace this with `Object.create`.

There is general rule that applies. It depends very much on what the constructor function is doing and how you inherit from other objects, etc.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but I still don't understand when you would use Object.create vs new?  Can you give a code example of the use of Object.create and explain why new wouldn't have worked?

Comment: @jfriend00: You would use `Object.create` if the sole purpose of a constructor function is to create an empty object that inherits from another object.

Comment: That helps, thanks.  It looks to me like it's a language-supported version of YUI extend() which is used for creating new object that inherits the prototype of another object.  Is that right?

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, `Object.create()` is commonly used when you want an easy way to set the prototype of a new object. What the other answers fail to mention though, is that constructor functions (which require new) are not all that different from any other function.

In fact, any function can return an object, and it's common in JavaScript to see factory functions (like constructors, but they don't require `new`, or use `this` to refer to the new object). Factory functions often use `Object.create()` to set the prototype of the new object.

```
var barPrototype = {
  open: function open() { /* ... */ },
  close: function close() { /* ... */ },
};
function createBar() {
  return Object.create(barPrototype);
}

var bar = createBar();
```

Answer (score 4):

Super late to this thread.. but I think an important distinction that needs to be made is that while constructors are just functions, the new operator invokes the function and captures the resulting object which can be useful when in a dynamic environment. It allows reference to properties and methods during execution of the constructor as well which may or may not be useful depending on the situation. If you are more concerned with having a set prototype but the object itself is more static than not, Object.create would be a better option as it is cleaner and doesn't mess with the proto-chain in unexpected ways as the new operator does.

some simple examples..

```
var Foo = function(element) {
  this.elem = element;
  $(this.elem).css('color', 'blue');
  // using the new operator here gives access to this.elem
  // immediately after that declaration is made, thus providing 
  // a comfortable dynamic system to work with 
}

var bar = new Foo(someElem);
```

as apposed to..

```
var foo = {
  elem : element,             // assume elem exists
  $(this.elem).css('color', 'blue')// in the lexical scope
}

var bar = Object.create(foo);
// This.elem does not exist until the object is returned now
// and the .css method call will not execute
```

It should be slightly clearer why you would want to use one over the other, as another simple breakdown...

Use New when you care about having a dynamic object and less about the prototype chain

Use Object.create when you care less about being dynamic and more about having an explicit prototype chain. I will also note that objects made with Object.create can be dynamically built as well by using a method called `init` that you can build to assign properties based on your needs and simply call it on your freshly returned object.

Each approach has it's ups and downs however their use cases are fairly distinct in my opinion. However, you will most likely find yourself using Object.create as most situations will call for a less dynamic situation and have more need for inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

The exact source code for the Object.create() function is:

```
function Object.Create(proto, propertiesObject)
{
    var obj = {};

    Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, proto);

    if(propertiesObject)
    {
        Object.defineProperties(obj, propertiesObject);
    }

    return obj;
}
```