# NodeJS export class with static methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

I’m trying to develop a class with static methods on a NodeJs application, as a Config module purpose.

I would like to access to it from different modules without instantiate every time a new object.

1) Is it correct to use an approach like below, avoiding the class prototype?

```
function Config(){

}

Config.svrPort=function(){
    return 8080;
}

Config.dbName=function(){
    return "myDbName";
}

module.exports = Config;
```

2) Are there any other solutions?

3) Is it also a valid approach to put different objects in the same module (e.g. config.js) like this?

```
exports.server=function(){
    return{
        port:8080
    };
};

exports.database=function(){
    return{
        name:"myDbName",
        user:"root",
        password:"myPassword",
        host:"localhost",
        port:3306
    };
};
```

and finally to use it as:

```
var config = require('./config');
config.server().port
config.database().name
```

Comment: why not just an object literal?

Comment: That is the correct approach although in your example you could simply store the values as primitives: `Config.SVR_PORT = 8080`, also note i rewrote those as "constants", since I don't recommend changing statics.

Comment: I agree with @dev-null. Just use `var Config = {SVG_PORT: 8080, ...}`. You can also use `Object.freeze`.

Comment: The latter approach is valid. For the first one you can just `mode.exports = new Config()`, so not exposing the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct approach although in your example you could simply store the values as primitives: `Config.SVR_PORT = 8080`, note I rewrote those as "constants", since I don't recommend changing statics.

When this is said, then please note: **Do not** put any sensitive data (passwords, etc) in your JavaScript files, but instead put these in a config file. This will separate config from code. And help you not to leak any potential critical information.

db-secrets.json

```
{
  "password": "...",
  ...
}
```

Then you can access the secrets by making a wrapper module:

```
// Wrapper module for db-secrets.json
var fs = require('fs');
exports = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('db-secrets.json'), 'utf8');
```

Or make a db connect module `db-connect.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var db = require('db');
var db_secrets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('db-secrets.json'), 'utf8');

export = function() {
  return db.connect(db_secrets.user, db_secrets.password, ...);
};
```

If you use git for source control you can easily add the following to your `.gitignore` which will make sure your sensitive file is not added to git:

.gitignore

```
db-secrets.json
```

Comment: I definitely agree with you to put the sensitive data into a sort of AppConfig JSON file and to wrap it into a module with  "exhaustive" Javascript objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are no classes in the prototype languages (it's just a syntax sugar that mimics the classical OOP). Hence no static methods. My guess is that you want a singleton (which is the same as `object literal`).

```
var Config = {
    get svrPort() {
        return 8080;
    },

    get dbName() {
        return "myDbName";
    },
};

// updated: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching
// module.exports = Object.create(Config);
module.exports = Config;
```

Comment: Why the `Object.create`?

Comment: @Louy Depends on the [concrete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613261/is-there-any-reason-to-use-object-create-or-new-in-javascript) usage.

Comment: @Vidul, just a question: what happens every time that I get a value from this object? Will be created a new instance of the object? 
Is this like an object with a factory method?

Comment: @DomenicoVacchiano Each time the module is `required`, a new object is [created](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). If you don't want this behaviour, just replace `Object.create(Config)` with `Config`. Getting a value from the [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) (if I understood the question correctly), does not impose a new object creation.

Comment: After the module is `required` for the first time, the value will be cached. Also, I don't see the point of `Object.create` here.

Comment: @StefanBaiu There is no caching, it is either a new object or the same one.

Comment: @Vidul @DomenicoVacchiano You are mistaken, the object is only created once, and each time the `require()` happens the same object is returned... you're better off simply exporting the singular object.

Comment: @Tracker1 You mean that `obj = {}; Object.create(obj) === obj; // is true`?

Comment: @Vidul The code in that file will only be executed once. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Comment: @Vidul `Object.create(obj) !== obj` ... `require('foo') === require('foo')` .. the code doesn't re-run, require returns the same exports that already processed ... also, there's no point in using the Object.create in this case.

Comment: @StefanBaiu My error, thank you for the point; the answer was updated.

Answer (score 1):

JS supports object literals, not to mention that you can export a single object, or multiple export properties on the default `exports` object...  When the `require('./your-module');` happens the code in the module is *not* run again, it simply returns the original export, that has it's own original context.

---

Just export each of the functions/variables that you want as either an object literal, or attached to the exports.

```
//just declare any private context as it's own variables in your module, these are static
var someVal = "this isn't visible outside the module";

//export single object, with methods attached
//  NOTE: by default exports exists, and is already module.exports
//  exports === module.exports
exports = module.exports = { 
  getSomeVal: function getSomeVal(){
    return someVal;
  },
  getSrvPort: function getSrvPort(){
    return 8000;
  }
  ...
}

//alternatively, export each method as property
//    note, you should name your function assignments, 
//    this helps with debugging.
exports.getDbName = function getDbName(){
  return "mydb";
};
```

The code only actually runs once and all places using it will see the same option.

---

As an aside, if you're using [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) with ES6 modules, you can simply declare your export with each method...

```
export function getSrvPort() {
  return 8000;
}

export function dbName() {
  return "mydb";
}
```