# Adding a property to a "Class" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

There are no actual classes in javascript. But you have to work with what you get.

Lets take this example "Class":

```
var example = function (string) {
  this._self = string;
}
```

With the above, you could do something like:

```
var ex = new example("Hello People."),
    display = ex._self; // returns "Hello People."
```

I thought that by using something like `example.prototype.newFun = function(){}` would add a new property to that "Class". But it isn't working in my code.

Here is the full code i'm testing:

```
var example = function (string) {
  this._self = string;//public, var like, storage
}

var showExample = new example("Hello People");
showExample.prototype.display = function (a) {//code stops here, with error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined"
  return a;
}
console.log(showExample._self);
console.log(showExample.display("Bye"));
```

What i'm trying to do is add the `display` function to the example function as a "public function". I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the object that has the prototype, it's the function that you use to create the object:

```
var example = function (string) {
  this._self = string;
}

example.prototype.display = function (a) {
  return a;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Because there's no prototype for `showExample` - it's only an instance of `example`. Try to do this: `example.prototype.display = function (a) {}` and it will work.

Here's a bit more on classes in JavaScript:

- [3 Ways to "define" classes](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)
- [This lovely SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/whats-the-best-way-to-define-a-class-in-javascript)
- I like the way [Classy](http://classy.pocoo.org/) handles this and also how classes are implemented in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#classes).

Answer (score 3):

You try to add a method to the `prototype` of the instance of `example` (showExample). The instance has no prototype. Try `example.prototype.display = function() {/*...*/};` (in other words, add the method to the `prototype` of the `constructor` of `showExample`, that is `example`) and check again. After that, all instances of `example` 'know' the `display` method, or in your words, `display` is 'public' to all instances.

You *can* add the method to the *instance* using `showExample.display = function() {/*...*/};`. Using that, only `showExample` knows the the `display` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify to the constructor of showExample ..

ex.

```
showExample.constructor.prototype.display = function (a) {
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case showExample is an object of example...

use

```
example.prototype.display = function(a)...
```