# Object cannot access JS constructor function

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. I am learning JS OOP's concepts. I am trying to use constructor to create private variables in JS. But when I try to access the values using getters, I get an error 'TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function '

```
function Card(n,s) {
    var number = n;
    var suit = s;
    //getters
    var getNumber = function(){
            return this.number;
    };
    var getSuit = function(){
            return this.suit;
    };
}
var test = new Card(10, 1);
test.getNumber();
```

I am not able to figure out what the error might be. Need some help on this.

Comment: `var` declares a variable in function scope. Recommended reading:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/387707/

Comment: You should prefer prototype based inheritance over what you have now, since it's more memory efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did not attach the functions to `this`, which points to the instance of the constructor. Properties and functions attached to `this` are like your "public" properties and methods in classical OOP.

Also, the variables `number` and `suit` live inside the instance but not as properties of the instance. They cannot be accessed via `this` because you didn't attach them. They act like "private variables" in classical OOP.

But since your getters are in the same scope (the constructor `Card`) as the variables, they have access to them, like the "getters" and "setters" of classical OOP.

```
function Card(n, s) {
  var number = n;
  var suit = s;
  //getters
  this.getNumber = function () {
    return number;
  };
  this.getSuit = function () {
    return suit;
  };
}
var test = new Card(10, 1);
test.getNumber();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
function Card(n,s) {
    this.number = n;
    this.suit = s;
}


    //getters
Card.prototype.getNumber =  function(){
        return this.number;
};
Card.prototype.getSuit = function(){
        return this.suit;
};

var test = new Card(10, 1);
test.getNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

The getters has to be member functions, ie it has to be defined on the `this` object.

In your case those getters are private to the constructor, it will not be accessible outside the constructor

```
function Card(n,s) {
    var number = n;
    var suit = s;
    //getters
    this.getNumber = function(){
            return this.number;
    };
    this.getSuit = function(){
            return this.suit;
    };
}
var test = new Card(10, 1);
test.getNumber();
```