# Method missing in JS

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In python I can do something like this:

```
class Converter(object):
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount

    def rupy(self):
        return self.amount * 2

    def __getattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args[0] == 'rupies':
            return self.rupy
```

Is JS provide some way to achieve the same behavior? I googled a bit and found  article about [**noSuchMethod**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) but it works only in Firefox.

Edit: I don't wan't to have aliases I want to have a way to handle method missing generically

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/whats-the-best-way-to-define-a-class-in-javascript

Comment: My question is concrete and I can't find an answer in topic provided by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer

> Does *JavaScript* have an equivalent to `__getattr__`?

No :(

---

Long answer

It looks like you just want to map aliases, *JavaScript* has no problem with adding properties to things like this

```
// set up
function Converter(amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
Converter.prototype.rupy = function () {
    return this.amount * 2;
};
// add aliases
var original = 'rupy', aliases = ['rupies'], i;
for (i = 0; i < aliases.length; ++i)
    Converter.prototype[aliases[i]] = Converter.prototype[original];
```

Now

```
var foo = new Converter(1);
foo.rupies(); // 2
```

and have

```
foo.rupies === foo.rupy; // true
```

---

Future answer

In *ECMAScript 6 (Harmony)* we have [*Proxies*](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies)

```
Constructor.prototype = Proxy(Constructor.prototype, {
    'get': function (target, name, child) {
            var o = child || target; /* =proxy? if proxy not inherited? */
            if (name in target) return o[name];
            if (name === 'rupies') return o['rupy'];
            return;
        },
    'set': function (target, name, val, child) {
            return target[name] = val;
        },
    'has': function (target, name) {
            return name in target; // do you want to make 'rupies' visible?
        },
    'enumerate': function (target) {
            for (var key in target) yield key;
        }
});
```