# Define a class with namespace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-namespaces

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/387733/418439,

```
// Define a class like this
function Person(name, gender){

   // Add object properties like this
   this.name = name;
   this.gender = gender;
}

// Add methods like this.  All Person objects will be able to invoke this
Person.prototype.speak = function(){
    alert("Howdy, my name is" + this.name);
}

// Instantiate new objects with 'new'
var person = new Person("Bob", "M");

// Invoke methods like this
person.speak(); // alerts "Howdy, my name is Bob"
```

How to define [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration) as well?

Comment: There are no namespaces in JavaScript.

Comment: @wumm There really aren't, but you can simulate them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just create a new object that contains all your classes/functions:

```
var myNamespace = {};

myNamespace.Person = function (name, gender) {
    // Add object properties like this
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}

myNamespace.Person.prototype.speak = function() {
    alert("Howdy, my name is" + this.name);
}

// Instantiate new objects with 'new'
var person = new myNamespace.Person("Bob", "M");

// Invoke methods like this
person.speak(); // alerts "Howdy, my name is Bob"
```

MDN has an [article explaining JavaScript namespacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/JavaScript_Object_Management).

Comment: `yNamespace.Person = Person(name, gender){` must be `yNamespace.Person = function(name, gender){`

Comment: @wumm Thanks, didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var namespace = {};

namespace.Person = function(name, gender) { ... };

var myPerson = new namespace.Person();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this ref:- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)

```
var yourNamespace = {

        foo: function() {
        },

        bar: function() {
        }
    };

    ...

    yourNamespace.foo();
```

Comment: Did you take this code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var MYNamespace = MYNamespace|| {};

 MYNamespace.MyFirstClass = function (val) {
        this.value = val;
        this.getValue = function(){
                          return this.value;
                       };
    }

var myFirstInstance = new MYNamespace.MyFirstClass(46);
alert(myFirstInstance.getValue());
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpaul/4dngxwb3/1/

Answer (score -1):

I once made an example file (for my own use), so I'll share that here, maybe you will find it useful (warning: it contains more than just namespaces):

```
//http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html
//http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/
//http://appendto.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/

//adding the whole shabang to a namespace
var NameSpace = (function (params) 
{

//initialising constructor with parameter
//call as "var testObject = new MyConstructor("test");"
//then accessing the public members: "testObject.publicMember = 123;"
function MyConstructor(param, param2)
{
    //initialising public instance member variables
    //these could also be added by calling "testObject.[newMemberName] = [value];" to create a new property
    //can be accessed by private and public methods
    this.publicMember = param;
    this.secondPublicMember;

    //initialising private instance member variables
    //private variables can only be added at creation time
    //can be accessed by private methods, but not by the object's own public methods.
    var privateMember = param2;
    var secondPrivateMember;

    //creates a private function, NOT accessible by public functions (ONLY by internal private and privileged ones)
    //has access to all private/public functions and variables?
    function PrivateFunction(params)
    {
        //place code here
        //note this notation is short for "var PrivateFunction = function PrivateFunction(params) {};"
    }

    //creates a privileged function, accessible by all public (and private?) functions
    //has access to all private/public functions and variables
    this.PrivilegedFunction = function (params)
    {
        //place code here
    };
}

//creating a public function, accessible by calling "testObject.PublicFunction(params)"
//can also be done by calling "testObject.[newFunctionName] = function (params) {};"
//has access to all public members and functions
MyConstructor.prototype.PublicFunction = function (params) 
{
    //place function code here
};
```

};

Again, this was just a mockup I made for myself using the links mentioned at the top.