# Instantiate object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create an class object in jquery? In java or C/C++, I can do

```
class People {
   String name;
   public People(name) { this.name = name;}
   public String getName( return this.name; }
}
```

How can I convert the snippet code above to jquery or javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to define a class in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/whats-the-best-way-to-define-a-class-in-javascript)

Comment: By the way, jQuery has nothing to do with classes. It's just a JavaScript library and as such can't add basic features like classes to the language.

Comment: The following may help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would only need to use a getter method for a private variable. You can define a constructor and instantiate new objects with the 'new' operator. If you want to create a private variable, use 'var' to define it. For public values, set them as instance properties using:

```
this.PROPERTY = VALUE
```

Here is my fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nhmaggiej/avvtpcyc/

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
function People(name){
      this.name=name;
      People.prototype.getName = function () {
         return this.name;
      }; 
}
var a=new People("a");
```

More about OOP of javascript,
you can read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp)

Comment: Why would you re define prototype every time you create an instance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score -1):

There are no classes in JavaScript. There are only objects (which are maps with String keys), which properties ('members') can be functions, allowing you to emulate methods; objects can inherit from other objects through a mechanism that is known as prototypal inheritance.