# Best way to reuse variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have an array in Javascript :

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push({ id: 0, value: 1 });
myArray.push({ id: 2, value: 3 });
```

Is there a way I do not have to define the var { id: 2, value: 3 } again and again?

Something which would allow me to create a variable and use it again like :

```
var something = { id: tempId, value: tempVal }
```

and then I can keep pushing new instances of something in the array?

Comment: Perhaps, but is there an equivalent of an object here? I am sorry I am new to JS. Like in Java it gives you a blueprint and you can create objects.

Comment: yes I will put it as an answer

Comment: Javascript is not Java. Writing your code as if it was is a mistake.

Comment: @Sverri I agree but I think OP is just trying to do Object Oriented Programming in JS which is a common thing

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen could you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: @EricPhillips Well, it would take a longer essay to explain the differences between the two languages, but it would boil down to the simple fact that they are just very different languages. Many languages are like this; Go, Ruby, C, Haskel, etc. You just do things in a certain way when using these languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I can understand from your comment you want a **function** that pushes an **object** to an array.

For javascript objects look here : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
Indeed, you have been creating classes all along.

```
function Something(id, value) {
                      this.id = id;
                      this.value = value
                 }
```

now when you are pushing this to an array you need to create an instance(an object)

such as

```
var something1 = new Something(1,2)
myArray.push(something1)
```

And if you want to access a field you will do

```
myArray[0]["id"]
```

see this question [What techniques can be used to define a class in JavaScript, and what are their trade-offs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-define-a-class-in-javascript-and-what-are-their)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!!