# How does Javascript know which function reference is a class?

Tags: javascript

Now I know this might be a stupid question, but I need to improve my understanding of the language. So first, please have a look at the simple code:

JS:

```
function Blog(body , date){
    this.body = body;
    this.date = new Date(date);
}

Blog.prototype.toString = function(){
    return '[' + (this.date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + this.getDate() + '/' + this.getFullYear() + ']' + this.body;
};
```

Now, we humans can clearly see that there is an object constructor for the `Blog` object, and there is a function that is owned by the `Blog` class. Now, end of the day, the constructor is still a `function`, a function which is written like any other function: same syntax, same kind of arguments etc.

Now here is my question: According to this, every function reference(which in this case, is `Blog`) can be a class. Is it true or not? And if that is not true, how does javascript know that `Blog` is a class and not just the reference to a function?

NOTE: I hope I made my point clear. If not, please tell me in the comments.

Comment: There is no difference between a function and a class.

Comment: there were never any "Classes" in js ,people used Pascal case for function names to specify constructors some called it class .but `class` keyword was added officially in js recently

Comment: might also be helpful to read the top answer here on what the `new` keyword actually does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: @SLaks: Semantically, there is a difference between callable and constructable objects. Of course, in practise every `function` definition (expression or declaration) is both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every function can be invoked with the `new` keyword in JavaScript, so every function can be used as a constructor.  However, only certain functions will create a useful object when called with `new`.

Comment: Notice this is no longer true with ES6

Answer (score 1):

Actually, nothing is a class in javascript. There are no classes. But *"we humans"* can pretend that they are classes. In that case, yes, every function can be a class ;)

See also: [What techniques can be used to define a class in JavaScript, and what are their trade-offs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-define-a-class-in-javascript-and-what-are-their)

Comment: Okay... I got what I wanted, thnx:)