# Using Classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, web

as a beginner I tried to use classes in JavaScript because I started to learn programming with C#.

So i want to store a note (with a title and a text) to a data store. These are my small classes:

```
class Note{ // The single note
  constructor(noteTitle, noteText) { // set the notes title and text
    title = noteTitle;
    text = noteText;
  }

  var title;
  var text;
}

class Notestore{
  var notes = []; // stores all the notes

  function AddNote(note){
    notes.push(note); // add a new note to the list
  }
}

class NoteController{
  var store = new NoteStore(); // get the reference to the store

  function CreateNote(title, text){ // create a new note and store it
    store.AddNote(new Note(title, text));
  }
}
```

So when I start the application it says,

```
var store = new NoteStore();
```

is not defined. My NoteController is the first class getting called. What do I have to change, that my classes should work =?

Thanks for help!

Comment: 1. You don't declare fields in classes. So remove `var title;` andd others. 2. You use `this.` to address the instance properties, not just a name. It actually is surprising that you can run your code, since it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `NoteStore !== Notestore` - and that's just the obvious typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What techniques can be used to define a class in JavaScript, and what are their trade-offs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-define-a-class-in-javascript-and-what-are-their)

Comment: well, that's solved then

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken about how to use instance variables/class attributes in Javascript. You need to assign them to `this` (e.g. `this.foo = 'bar'`). You also made some mistakes about declaring methods, you do not need to use the `function` keyword. Here is your code, updated to properly use instance variables:

```
class Note { // The single note
  constructor(noteTitle, noteText) { // set the notes title and text
    this.title = noteTitle;
    this.text = noteText;
  }
}

class NoteStore {
  constructor() {
    this.notes = []; // stores all the notes
  }
  AddNote(note){
    this.notes.push(note); // add a new note to the list
  }
}

class NoteController {
  constructor() {
     this.store = new NoteStore(); // get the reference to the store
  }
  CreateNote(title, text){ // create a new note and store it
    this.store.AddNote(new Note(title, text));
  }
}

var store = new NoteStore();
```

Comment: Also want to add that the OP should be using camelcase names for their methods, ie. addNote and createNote - not AddNote and CreateNote.

Comment: You are correct that is currently the trend to use camelCase for JS variables, functions and methods and UpperCamelCase for class names. I think this UpperCamelCase is common/popular in C#, Go, and a few other languages

Answer (score 0):

First you call your class Notestore. Then you try to use it as NoteStore with a capital S.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected it before posting it, but had an old copy of the code

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a case-sensitive language.  Try changing

```
class Notestore{
  ...
}
```

to

```
class NoteStore{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected it before posting it, but had an old copy of the code