# Sub-classing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would one go about in subclassing a class in jQuery?

Specifically, I want to be able to subclass this class:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm

and override its methods.

Some syntax helpers would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript uses prototypal inheritance.  Crockford has an excellent article on [how that's different from classical inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html).  Prototypal inheritance in JavaScript allows you to do all sorts of things that C++, Java, C#, etc. may not allow you to do and in ways that you may not expect.  Because that's what's built into Javascript, others have created methods of extension such as [closure-based](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2008/12/javascript-inheritance-via-prototypes-and-closures) inheritance where classes are created with closures instead of the standard formula.

The library that you linked to states in its [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp/overview_api.htm) that is based on [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/), *not* jQuery.  The two are both Javascript frameworks and are different.

For inheritance in dojo I doubt you could do much better than the [references in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355848/how-can-i-emulate-classes-in-javascript-with-or-without-a-3rd-party-library/356343#356343) to a similar question about inheritance in dojo.  One option suggests looking at `dojo.delegate();` and `dojo.declare();`.  [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-dojo/) has a good overview of classes using dojo in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Douglas Crockford's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) article, [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html). It's really well written and includes different examples of inheritance in Javascript.